# Trigger a function from child component and define in parent component in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Define a functions in parent component and call in child component in react native how can achieve this functionality in react native

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can achieve it using `callback function reference`.

**GrandParent**

```
class GrandParent extends Component {

                Fun=()=>{
                    console.log(1);
                }

                render(){
                    //passed the ref for GrandFunRef in Parent component
                    return (<Parent GrandFunRef={this.Fun} >)
                }
}
```

**Parent**

```
    class Parent extends Component {

                parentFun=()=>{
                    console.log(1);
                }

                render(){
                    //passed the ref for GrandFunRef in Child component
                    return (<Child GrandFunRef={this.props.GrandFunRef} >)
                }
}
```

**Child**

```
class Child extends Component {

        componentDidMount(){

            this.props.GrandFunRef(); // call the Parent parentFun
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but i have situation like this define a function in Grandparent component and call in child component how can i will achieve this,please send link demo if you have.

Comment: Thanks this will helpful for me.

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote it if its working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you have large tree, instead of “prop drilling” and it’s super annoying. You can use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Thanks this will helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function Parent() {
    // do something meaningful
    return <Child onClick={() => console.log('Handling any click referencing me')}/>
}

function Child({onClick}) {
    // do something meaningful
    return <button onClick={onClick}/>
}
```

Comment: Yes same like this,i have solve this issues thank you for replay.